# Can't set text on pushpins in Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps, pushpin

I'm following [the example here](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#Pushpins4) but I don't get to see the text, only the pushpins themselves. What can I be missing?

```
for (index in centers)
  map.entities.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(centers[index]), 
    { text: "A", visible: true, textOffset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 5) });
```

The array *centers* is just a set of points and, since I get the pushpins to appear at the right locations, I believe that the error is in the options.

Note that I'm trying to reuse the default pushpins as far as I can and intentionally omit the custom icon. In case I have to use a custom icon (which would be a shame), where can I find a set of pushpins looking like the default one (possibly in various colors)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From bing interactive sdk.
Just delete the line with the custom pin from you pushpinOptions and you will get the default push pin with text.

The error in you code that you pass the pushpinOptions as parameter to map.entities.push method, but the options is a parameter of  new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin method.

```javascript
var offset = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 5); 
var pushpinOptions = { text : '1', visible: true, textOffset: offset}; 
var pushpin= new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(
  new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6, -122.33), 
  pushpinOptions); 
map.entities.push(pushpin);
```